# Set div background image from file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that allows me to upload images :-)

Is it possible when I select an image to upload, it sets the white area with the image as a background image & also removes the text 'Select Image'.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vafk2Lhy/)**

Code:

```js
$("input[name='FileOne']").on("change", function(event1) {
      src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
      document.getElementById("FileOne").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+src1+')';
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .form-file-upload-container {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px
    }
}

.form-file-upload {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 48.5%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 31.3333%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 22.75%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 14.1666667%;
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 3%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 3%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

.form-file-upload-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 133.33333%
}

.form-file-upload label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #AFAFB4;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}

.form-file-upload span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.form-file-upload span:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
    background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.svg) no-repeat center center #fff;
    background-size: 65px 56px;
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.form-file-upload input {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1
}

.form-file-upload .close {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
<div class="form-file-upload-inner">
        <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span></label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span><button class="close" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. But you're selecting the wrong element here:

```
document.getElementById("FileOne")
```

It should be:

```
document.querySelector("[for=FileOne]")
```

If you use the former, you're going to select the input field itself, that you've correctly rendered invisible. You have to target the area you want to fill with the image. In your case, the `<label>` element should be fine, because it also defines the clickable area.

Comment: Excellent! https://jsfiddle.net/vafk2Lhy/1/ Is it also possible to hide `.form-file-upload span`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Well, sure, you can apply `display: none` to it for example. Watch out though, because there's a `<span>` inside `<label>` but also another one that wraps `<input>`.

Comment: Aaah. Do you know how I target that using Javascript?

Comment: For example, `[for=FileOne] > span` could do.